# Which image formats are not destructive?

Tags: image, image-processing, encryption

Suppose i want to convert some data into image. In this scenario pixels of image contain my data. Also i want to retrieve my original data from image. Is it possible ? Or image compression algorithms destruct color of pixels? is there any image format that does not destruct color of pixels like`.JPG`?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the file size? If not you could use 24bit RGB raw bitmap file.

Comment: Yes, file size matters too.

Answer (score 0):

I think `.PNG` is what i want. According to [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) `.PNG` uses lossless data compression algorithm.

Comment: If size matters - "WebP ... provides lossless and lossy compression". Becouse in some case png can not compress image and size can be huge. But webp has some drawbacks too.